# how to post html tag in retrofit android

Tags: android, html, retrofit

I need to use the following format payload in post method in retrofit. I need to post html  tags as string. If we can't do this in retrofit, how can we do that?

```
{
"text": "<p>ffsdsdf <span class=\"mention\" data-index=\"0\" data-denotation-char=\"@\" data-id=\"12fe9af4-e2d6-47cb-9601-64c7a1fe9c4a\" data-value=\"Vendor 3 company Vendor\"><span contenteditable=\"false\"><span class=\"ql-mention-denotation-char\">@</span>Vendor 3 company Vendor</span></span> </p>",
"users": ["12fe9af4-e2d6-47cb-9601-64c7a1fe9c4a"]}
```

Update:
All I need to create a  tag according to the number of users I get.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface placeApi {
@GET("/{id}")
public void getDataAPICall(@EncodedPath("text") TypedString text,
   Callback<Model> response);
}
```

Try this.